# Visual C# converting custom IEnumerable to string[]

Tags: c#, arrays, string, visual-studio, plugins

I am writing a plugin code in C# and there is a custom IEnumerable that is in fact an array of strings. However no string operations can be done on the array elements because they are not of the type `<string>`. But I need them to be strings and I have to operate on them as strings.

So I have added these 2 lines of code to turn the array into string:

```cs
var arrayRawSourceText = EditorController.ActiveDocument.ActiveSegmentPair.Source.AllSubItems.ToArray();
string[] arraySourceText = new string[arrayRawSourceText.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < arrayRawSourceText.Length; i++) { arraySourceText[i] = arrayRawSourceText[i].ToString(); }
```

Only two lines, yet I wonder if there is a simpler way of converting the array to `<string>`. Like a lambda expression or any other way to make this simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `AllSubItems` implement [IEnumerable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable(v=vs.110).aspx) I guess this code snippet should work :

```
var arraySourceText = EditorController.ActiveDocument
                                      .ActiveSegmentPair
                                      .Source
                                      .AllSubItems
                                      .Select(t => t.ToString())
                                      .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen you already accepted an answer, But for further searchers maybe this will fit too:

```
var arraySourceText = EditorController.ActiveDocument
                                  .ActiveSegmentPair
                                  .Source
                                  .AllSubItems
                                  .Cast<string>()
                                  .ToArray();
```

Comment: `Cast<string>()` does not work, but the lambda expression does. I believe the casting is much more limited. Thanks though.